# setup redis cluster on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster

I want to create a master + slave Redis cluster. Tables will be prefixed for each environment. Any piece of codes that supports the above feature would be helpful.

Comment: Refers to helm charts: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/redis

Answer (score 1):

More complicated K8s deployments are best done with Helm, since they are easily (and highly configurable). This is the location of a well maintained open-source helm chart for redis cluster:

https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis-cluster

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2020/10/01/redis-ha-master-slave-cluster-up-and-running-in-openshift-okd-kubernetes/) is how you can setup Redis HA Master Slave Cluster in Kubernetes/Openshift OKD, without using Helm

Basically you have to use configMap, StatefulSet in collaboration with VolumeClaims

Comment: Any idea about setting up the Redis cluster into two openshift clusters?
it means, having two openshift clusters named A and B
we want to deploy the master Redis into openshift A, and slave Redis in openshift B
for each openshift platform we set up two sentinel Redis